# How to I fix this? [ WARN:0@0.017] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('licensed-image.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I am trying to a write Python program for edge detection and I am getting these problems and errors and I don't understand why.

Here is my program:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('licensed-image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Define Sobel masks for horizontal and vertical edge detection
sobel_x = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                    [-2, 0, 2],
                    [-1, 0, 1]])

sobel_y = np.array([[-1, -2, -1],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [1, 2, 1]])

# Perform convolution operations using cv2.filter2D
horizontal_edges = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, sobel_x)
vertical_edges = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, sobel_y)

# Combine the horizontal and vertical edge masks to obtain the final edge image
edge_image = np.sqrt(np.square(horizontal_edges) + np.square(vertical_edges))
edge_image = np.uint8(edge_image)

# Display the original image and the edge-detected image
cv2.imshow('Original Image', image)
cv2.imshow('Edge-Detected Image', edge_image) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Save the edge-detected image
cv2.imwrite('edge_detected_image.jpg', edge_image)
```

**This is the problem shown by vs code referring to "edge_image" in lines 26 and 31**

> Argument of type "uint8" cannot be assigned to parameter "mat" of type "UMat" in function "imshow"
> "uint8" is incompatible with "UMat"

**ERROR**

> [ WARN:0@0.017] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('licensed-image.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\coding stuff\edge_detect\edge.py", line 17, in 
> horizontal_edges = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, sobel_x)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\filter.dispatch.cpp:1530: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::filter2D